# Varnish : How to Fix WordPress Website Not Updating?

Tags: wordpress, memcached, varnish, litespeed

I installed Memcache and Varnish cache and litespeed on my server,some pages on my wordpress website not updating after create new posts and I have to press Ctrl+F5 to show new posts,how can I fix this problem? and this problem is about litespeed or Memcache and Varnish?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is the main purpose of Varnish implementation. Old cache content you see, due to Varnish cache. You can use below plugin.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/varnish-http-purge/

It will purge Varnish Cache when post content on your site is modified.So, you can get updated content whenever something updated on your WordPress.